# HTML5: How to pause when using Onclick for custom button?

Tags: custom-controls, html5-audio

I'm using the following code I found on SO for the iphone app i'm working on,

```
<a onclick="this.firstChild.play()">
    <audio src=".."></audio>
    Here's where I insert my custom player button
</a>
```

But I can't pause the music, can anyone tell me where should i insert `pause()`?

Answer (score 2):

how about this to get you started? Test it [here on this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/75lb/6uTcf/).

```
<audio id="player" src=".."></audio>

<a href="javascript:;" onclick="document.getElementById('player').play();">Play</a>
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="document.getElementById('player').pause();">Pause</a>
```

Comment: Hi thanks Lloyd!I just tried that t works perfectly on the browser. But because I'm using this for the iphone app so only the <a onclick="this.firstChild.play()"> actually plays music, is it possible to add other codes into it for the pause functionality?

Comment: changed my answer to use `a` tags instead of `button`

Comment: Cool! I just found out it's working now! thanks alot! Can i add style to customize the button??

Comment: if you want a custom CSS button style i'd switch to using `a` tags like in my answer

Comment: Ok, good.. Don't forget to accept the answer if it answered your question!

Comment: hi, to accept the answer click the "tick" icon to the left of the answer